# Swift: App crashes when UITableView scrolled too fast

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, swift2

I'm creating a page where user selects the industry they're in from a list of industries in a UITableView. This is a part of a profile creation process. When user selects an industry, it gets checkmarked (if not previously selected) & un-checkmarked (if previously selected).

I've got the code working and it's able to build successfully. Everything works fine, but when I scroll too fast, the app crashes with the following error:

> 2015-10-29 10:16:40.576 Protégé Version 1.0[10867:473794] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'

It is followed by "First throw call stack" and the listing of all the files. Strangely enough, this seems to only happen when I scroll it too fast. Often happens all of a sudden as well.

Here's my code below. Have searched online for anything related to the error message I got and nothing seems to be helpful for this scenario. Can't seem to figure out what's wrong and would really appreciate any help. I'm new to Swift so let me know if there are any errors in my code! Thanks in advance :)

```
var array = ["Industry 1", "Industry 2", "Industry 3", "Industry 4", "Industry 5"]
var itemsSelected: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

**To determine how many rows there are**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}
```

**To define content of each individual cell**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

    for var i = 0; i < selectedCells.count; i++ {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedCells[i], inSection: 0)
            let checkedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
            checkedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

    return cell
}
```

**To create array to store cells that are selected**

```
var selectedCells: [Int] = []
```

**To select rows - checkmark & un-checkmark**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    // Checkmark & un-checkmark cell
    if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    // Add cell # to selectedCells array if it's a new selection. Remove if it's a deselection.
    if selectedCells.contains(indexPath.row) {
        selectedCells = selectedCells.filter {$0 != indexPath.row}
    } else {
        selectedCells.append(indexPath.row)
    }

    print(selectedCells)
}
```

**Transfer selected string to main profile creation view controller**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "selectionCompleted" {

        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController
        let destViewController: CreateProfileViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CreateProfileViewController

        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        destViewController.displayedSelection = array[0]
    }
}
```

**Increase speed of segue back to main profile creation view controller**

```
override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if identifier == "selectionCompleted" {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectionCompleted", sender: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please print the indexPath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath and try to scroll it too fast?
This might be causing because your indexPath.row value is more than the values in your array.

Comment: I don't think the indexPath.row of accessing the array that store strings made problem since the numbers of cell seems to be returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the context you provided. I guess the problem may occur because of your "content define method" and selected checking mechanism.

My guess:

In you tableView(*:UITableView*:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell function,
It loop pass your selectedArray every time when the delegate ask for a cell.

And due to NSArray(array) isn't thread safe, any changing or rapid accessing of the selectedCell array may lead to various statuses. When "scrolling so fast" would create many loops that access the same array in the same time, I think the some conflicts may occur here.

Let me give a suggestion. You may use a Set instead of the array. Use "contain""insert""remove" to control the statuses and every cell manage only itself.

May be something like:

```
let cell = ...
...
if selectedSet.contains(indexPath.row){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}else{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
...
return cell
```